# How to use format to put a string between two % signs in php?

Tags: php, format

I want a string to be placed between two `%` signs. `sprintf('\%%s\%', 'hello')` returns `%s%`. What is wrong here?

Comment: `%%` not `\%`.. [Documentation](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: @JonStirling, Thanks

Comment: `echo sprintf('%%%s%%', 'Hello'); #output: '%Hello%'`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, percent signs (%) are used for escaping characters instead of slashes (/), so what you're looking for is:

```
sprintf('%%%s%%', 'hello');
```

It's a bit confusing to see so many percent signs in a row, but that's just how it works!

Comment: Forward slashes (`/`) **are not** used to escape anything in PHP. And the percent sign (`%`) is a special character only in the format string used by the functions from the [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) family.